# Testing the faithfulness of group homomorphisms by testing on the level of induced Lie Algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-algebras, abstract-algebra, braid-groups

> Let $G$ be a group and let $\Gamma_G(k)$ be the $k$th term of the
>   lower central series of $G$. For each $k\geq 1$, set
>   $\mathrm{gr}_k(G)=\Gamma_G(k)/\Gamma_G(k+1)$ and
>   $$\mathrm{gr}_*(G):=\bigoplus_{k\geq 1}\mathrm{gr}_k(G).$$ Then
>   $\mathrm{gr}_*(G)$ has a graded Lie algebra structure induced from the
>   commutator bracket on $G$. The following lemma is quoted from *Braids:
>   Introductory Lectures on Braids, Configurations and Their
>   Applications* by A Jon Berrick, Frederick R Cohen, Elizabeth Hanbury,
>   Yan-Loi Wong, Jie Wu:

[image]

> Since pure braid groups $P_n$ are residually nilpotent, the lemma
>   provides a testing whether certain group homomorphism $f:P_n\to G$ are
>   faithful by testing whether induced morphisms on the level of Lie
>   algebras $\mathrm{gr}_*(f):\mathrm{gr}_*(P_n)\to\mathrm{gr}_*(G)$ are
>   faithful.
>
> So far everything seems clear; but here is an extract from *On
>   Injective Homomorphisms For Pure Braid Groups, And Associated Lie
>   Algebras* by F. R. Cohen And Stratos Prassidis:

[image]
[image]

> (some contents are omitted)

[image]

---

> Now my question is: As we mentioned, Lemma 18.2 provides a testing
>   whether certain group homomorphism $f:P_n\to G$ are faithful by
>   testing whether induced morphisms on the level of Lie algebras
>   $\mathrm{gr}_*(f):\mathrm{gr}_*(P_n)\to\mathrm{gr}_*(G)$ are faithful.
>   **Why is Theorem 1.1 also related to this?**
>
> By the way, for the notation, in Cohen's paper $E^*_0(G)$ is the same
>   as $\mathrm{gr}_*(G)$ defined before.